# Looking For A Way To Allow a Client To See Real-Time Updates for NativeScript App Project

Tags: android, ios, angular, mobile, nativescript

So I've been learning Javascript, TypeScript, Angular, and NativeScript for several months now and I just took on an app development project for a client. I know that there are emulators that you can use to see how what you've developed might look on an iOS and Android device. I also know about the NativeScript Preview app that you can download from app stores. The problem with the Preview app is that it doesn't appear to be compatible with certain Angular plugins like Firebase...unless I'm just doing something wrong perhaps.

I'm looking for a way to show my client where I'm at in my development so that he isn't left in the dark about what I'm doing. This is very easy to do with regards to web development, but what are my options regarding mobile development? I'm using NativeScript + Angular + Firebase...that's my stack of choice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've already tried the Preview app which worked at first until I installed the Firebase plugin, then I got an error code and according to some on Stack Overflow, it's because the Preview app is limited in terms of what it can do.

I'm wondering if there's a way to save changes on my end and allow the client to see those changes on his end.

Answer (score 2):

It's more similar to web, you deploy a build to your server and let your client access it.

Here with mobile apps, you will release a build to TestFlight / Google Play (Closed Beta Test) and let your client install the build on his device.

There are also third party services like [HockyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/), [TestFairy](https://www.testfairy.com/), and more. You may even share the IPA / APK via Email and let your client install them on his device.

There is also [App Sync](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-app-sync) support since {N} v6.0 to support over the air updates.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I'll check these out and see which works best